# Error in installing twilio as its not in AWS library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using twlio moodule which is not present in AWS module, so i have written code using twlio module and to get it install in aws server, i have run the command in the same parent folder names "abc" and that contain one python file "alert.py" in which i have written our code using:

```
from twilio.rest import Client


def send(event=None, context=None):
    my_body = "EC2 stopped working"
    client = Client("SID FROM TWILIO", "AUTH TOKEN FROM TWILIO")
    client.messages.create(to='+91indianNumber',
                           from_='+18TRIAL NUMBER',
                           body=my_body)
    return "Sent Message"
```

So this was my code and to install, i have tun the command 
**pip install twilio -t .**  and this will create so many other files.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rs9pV.png)

and when i am creating zip file and upload in aws lambda, in handler its coming like "lambda_function.lambda_handler" instead of "alert.send" as my file name was alert.py and function name was send (def send).

Can anyone explain.

Comment: How are you uploading it? `lambda_function.lambda_handler` is the default, but you can change the default

Comment: Also, your title doesn't seem to match your description at all? You haven't described any problem installing twilio, only configuring the lambda

Comment: Agreed with @jordanm. Your title isn't matching with the description _(edit the title)_ . As pointed by jordanm, by default the handler name will be `lambda_function.lambda_handler` but, as you are creating your python script, you will need to edit the default handler name with your `fileName:functionName` i.e. `alert.send`